# How to create an automatic change machine in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to programming. I've been trying to create something that would give me the minium amount of us cents coints required to a specific amount of dollars. For example, minimum amount of coins needed for 16 cents would be 3 (10 + 5+ 1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

float get_positive_change(void);

int main (void)
{   //Get owed dollar amount
 float change = get_positive_change();

//Round float to int
 int cents = round(change*100);

//Initialize counter for coins needed)
 for(int i = 0; cents < 0; i++)
 {

   if(cents >= 25)
   {
       cents = cents - 25;


   }
   else if(cents >= 10)
   {
       cents = cents - 10;

   }
   else if(cents >= 5)
   {
       cents = cents - 5;

   }
   else if(cents >= 1)
   {
       cents = cents - 1;

   }
   return cents;
   return i;
 }

  printf("%d\n", i);
}



float get_positive_change(void)
{
float n;
do
{
    n = get_float("Change owed: ");
}
while (n < 1); //Express need for number to be < 1
return n;
}
```

I do realize that "int i" does not exist outside of that function so, I'd like to know how to fix that. Also, I am not sure how return works yet, I was trying to play around and see if it worked. Any help to improve this code lines would be MUCH appriciated. I've been trying to solve this for a while now.
Wish you all a great day

Comment: Also, I don't remember if the "for loop" is actually a function or a statement, or neither. So, excuse me for any misunderstanding.

Comment: This is quite a classic problem on [Dynamic Programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-the-coin-change-problem-with-dynamic-programming/). Try read about it :)

Comment: Hint: try generating change for 23 cents.

Comment: See [coin change program using dynamic programming knapsack with repetitions allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35917610/3422102) and look at the **Related** links on the right.

Comment: 'float change' I was looking for that as soon as I read the title:((

Comment: @Uduru dynamic programming solves the general problem, but for US and Euro coins it's not needed — the greedy algorithm gives the correct answer always. I believe this is an exercise expecting the use of the greedy algorithm :)

Comment: @hobbs Ha, didn't realize the "us" word appeared there. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I don't remember if the "for loop" is actually a function or a statement, or neither.

`for` is a statement. A function is a named routine defined with:

`type name(parameter declarations…) { statements and declarations… }`.

(There are other forms of function definition in older C code. You should not use them.)

> I do realize that "int i" does not exist outside of that function so, I'd like to know how to fix that.

Move the `int i` outside of the `for` statement. Put it just before the `for` statement. You can still initialize `i` in the `for` statement:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; 0 < cents; ++i)
{
    …
}
```

This also corrects the termination condition. You had `cents < 0`. The loop executes as long as the condition is true, but `cents < 0` is false from the start, unless the amount owed is expressed as a negative number. Normally, it is a positive number, and you want to continue the loop as long as money is owed.

> Also, I am not sure how return works yet,…

`return` terminates execution of the current function. Execution resumes in the function that called the current function. A `return` with a value provides that value to the calling function as the value of the function call. For `main`, the return value provides a status value for the program. Returning with a non-zero value may result in a warning message that the program finished unsuccessfully.

You do not want to return results of calculations by using `return` in `main`. Instead, you probably want to print them, using `printf` statements. Refer to the text of your assignment for information on how the program is supposed to provide its results.

This code cannot work:

```
return cents;
return i;
```

because the first `return` terminates execution of `main`, so the second `return` is never executed.

This code in `get_positive_change` is wrong:

```
while (n < 1); //Express need for number to be < 1
```

because `n` may be a positive amount of money less than 1, such as (about) .16 dollars for 16 sents. You want `while (n <= 0)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I will make it in C++ since I've done more with that than C, but you can easily translate printf 's and inputs into C very easily

```cpp
//inside of main
int pennies = 0, nickels = 0, dimes = 0, quarters = 0;
int coinCounter = 0;
int amount = 0;

cout << "input the change you have in cents";
cin >> amount;

while(amount > 0)
{
    if(amount >= 25){
        quarters++;
        amount -= 25;
    }
    else if(amount >= 10) {
        dimes++;
        amount -= 10;
    }
    else if(amount >= 5) { 
        nickels++;
        amount -= 5;
    }
    else { //the only coin left would be pennies
        pennies++
        amount -= 1;
    }
    coinCounter++;
}

cout << "You have " + coinCounter + " coins\n";
cout << "You have " + quarters + " quarters\n";
cout << "You have " + dimes + " dimes\n";
cout << "You have " + nickels + " nickels\n";
cout << "You have " + pennies + " pennies\n";
```

I used a while loop in this situation because we don't know how much money can be made with the amount that is going to be inputted. You shouldn't use returns in main because that would quit out of main. Also, I wouldn't have 1 input statement in a function if I could do it inside of main as one line. It's not worth the aggravation at this point in your journey. You should learn how to use functions, but sometimes it's easier to do it the simple way. When you start calculating things before doing other things, then use a function. I know it is ment to make sure the user doesn't break the program, but that could be in main for right now.

You are going to have to do a lot more to get the right thing up, but I hope I helped spur your brain on.

Comment: No worries, you can just indent it all by 4-spaces to format as code, or just wrap in `\`\`\`c++` followed by `\`\`\`` (as you did, but without the spaces for indent). Welcome to SO. Also, while no dings here, you generally don't want to provide C++ answers to C questions, but as you say, here the only C++ is `std::cout` rather than `printf()` so it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I am also looking to get into C++, so this is a nice peek into it.